# Simple weighted rating value

Tags: algorithm, weighted-average

I have a database consisting of clubs and its ratings people have provided them with.

Currently, I am performing an average of the ratings based on a club and then sorting these averages in descending order to have a list of highest rated clubs.

The problem I am having is there should be some weighting based on how many ratings you have. **A club might get 5 (5.0) ratings and end up at the top of the list against a club that has 16K ratings and is also averaged with a 5.0 rating.**

What I'm looking for is the algorithm which factors in the number of ratings to ensure we are querying the data with a weighted algorithm that takes in the number of ratings.

Currently my algorithm is:

```
(sum of club ratings)/(total number of ratings) to give me the average
```

This does not incorporate the weight algorithm

Comment: For that you need the range of the actual rating. Like suppose, your actual rating can be from `0k` to `100k`. Then that has to be mapped to `0k` to `5k`.

Comment: @Haris Can you further explain and possibly provide the algorithm for weighted rating values

Answer (score 0):

Lets suppose your ratings can go from `0k` to `100k`(as you said some club has `16k` rating). Now you want that to be normalized to a range of `0k` to `5k`.

---

Lets say `0k` to `100k` is actual range. (A_lower to A_higher)

And, `0k` to `5k` is the normalized range. (N_lower to N_higher)

You want to change `16k`, which is A_rating(Actual rating) to a normalized value which is N_rating(inbetween `0 to 5k`).

---

*The formula* that you can use for this is

```
N-rating = A_rating * ( (N_higher - N_lower) / (A_higher - A_ lower) )
```

---

**Lets take an example.**

If the actual rating is `25k`. The range of the actual rating is from `0 to 100k`. And you want it normalized between `0 to 5k`. Then

```
N-rating = 25 * ( (5 - 0) / (100 - 0) )
=> N_rating = 1.25
```

---

**EDIT**

*A little more explanation*

We do [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_%28statistics%29), if there are values that are spread in a big range, and we want to represent them in a smaller range.

**Q) What is a normalized value.**

It is the value that would represent the exact place of the actual value(25k), if the Actual range(0 to 100) was a little smaller(0  to 5).

**Q) why am i taking the division of a normalized range to a actual range and then multiplying by the actual rating.**

To understand this, lets use a little of unitary method logic.

You have a value `25` when the range is `0 to 100`, and would want to know what the value be normalized to if the range was `0 to 5`. So,

```
//We will take already known values, the highest ones in both the ranges
100 is similar to 5 //the higher value of both the ranges
//In unitary method this would go like
If 100 is 5

//then 

1 is (5 / 100)

//and

x is x * (5 / 100) //we put 25 in place of x here
```

**Q) why did you choose 0 to 5k as the normalized range.**

I chose because you mentioned your rating should be below `5k`. You can choose any range you wish.

Comment: I'd like to understand how this weight works. What is a normalized value and why am i taking the division of a normalized range to a actual range and then multiplying by the actual rating?Also, why did you choose 0 to 5k as the normalized range.  I really just want to understand the algorithm before using it.

Comment: @jkushner, i have edited the answer and tried to explain, take a look. :)

Answer (score 0):

What about simply adding the number of rating weighted wit a very little value?
This is just a very basic idea:

(sum of club ratings)/(total number of ratings)+0.00000001*(number of club ratings)

This way clubs with same average get ranked by number of ratings.

Comment: I apologize I don't understand this algorithm at all. Can you explain how this algorithm works in full detail explaining each step. thanks

Comment: It is simply a little modification of your average calculation. It adds a little weight on the number of ratings. This way when clubs have same average rating the one with more ratings is lightly rated higher.

Comment: I like your idea. My question is why did you choose such a small multiplier (0.00000001)

Comment: To avoid that no matter how high the difference in the number of ratings is, only the number of ratings matters, if the average rating is exactly equal.

Comment: Sounds good. Ill test your theory out and let you know if it works. I appreciate the assistance.

Comment: shouldn't the last variable be the number of club ratings?

Comment: someone who scores an average of 4.7 with 500 votes gets a lower score than someone who scores an average of 5.0 with just 1 vote because the multiplier never allows the 4.7 to achieve a higher value if added to this small die number.

Comment: @jkushner that was what I intended only clubs with same average rating are ordered by the number of ratings.